# Unique id from table while joining

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

having the following scheme:

```
Table ticket

 - **ticketid** int;
 - **terr** int;

Table terrlocation

 - **terrid** int;
 - **terr_desc** int;
```

So, after executing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket tck
LEFT JOIN terrlocation ter on tck.terr = ter.terrid
```

I'll get:

```
ticketid | terr | terrid | terr_desc
--------------------------------------
01       | 02   | 02     | A      
01       | 02   | 02     | B
01       | 02   | 02     | C
```

But my task is to check, if there any records in terrlocation which is connected to ticket, than I get e.g. 1 and if not than 0. I can achive it through case, BUT, atm I get 3 records instead of one.

It seems to me that i need to put subquery in LEFT JOIN something like

```
SELECT * FROM ticket tck LEFT JOIN ((SELECT DISTINCT FROM terrid)
terrlocation ter on tck.terr = ter.terrid)
```

But it doesn't working. How can I achive my aim? M.b. through CTE is better?

Comment: Man I am trying hard to understand what are you trying to do ... can you just rather put down "wanted output" as you did for your first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `DISTINCT` you have to specify the columns that have to be distincted! Try this:

```
SELECT tck.*,CASE WHEN t.terrid is null THEN 0 else 1 end as Your_IND
FROM ticket tck
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT  terrid FROM terrlocation) t
 on tck.terr = t.terrid
```

Comment: Shame on me, so fullish mistake. Thanks for help.